# Записать в NodeJS набор файлов асинхронно

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

В приложении NodeJS есть необходимость асинхронной записи множества файлов. 
Пытаюсь делать так:

```
for (var l = 0; l < self.contentHyperLinks.length; l++) {
     var _nameChapter = config.out_folder +      getNameChapter(self.contentListItems[l]);
     var chapter_stream = Fs.createWriteStream(_nameChapter); // запись заглушки html
     var writeStreamAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(
        chapter_stream.once('open', function (fd) {
      chapter_stream.write(self.contentHyperLinks[l]);
      chapter_stream.end();
    })
  );
  self.Observables.push(writeStreamAsObservable);
}

  const observable = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(self.Observables);
  observable.subscribe(
  () => { },
  err => { },
  () => console.log('This is how it ends!')
    );
```

При выполнении приложения происходит ошибка

```
_stream_writable.js:357
  var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
                                    ^

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
   at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:357:42)
   at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
   at WriteStream.<anonymous> (D:\projects\webHelp\projects \100219_dev_rxjs_compat\src\ContentReader\content-reader.js:94:26)
   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at WriteStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at fs.open (fs.js:2170:10)
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

ЧТо я делаю не так ? Насколько вообще идея правильна асинхронной записи файлов для NodeJS ? Спасибо.

Comment: а где в приведенном примере код, на который указывает ошибка?

Comment: Ошибку показывает на модуль работы с потоками, к сожалению строка моего кода в ошибке не приводится.

Comment: Заменить `var l` на `let l`. У вас классическая ошибка, вы обращаетесь к переменной цикла в коллбеке